# Where can I find articles of incorporation for Canadian financial institutions?

Tags: canada, financial-literacy

[Search for a Federal Corporation](https://www.ic.gc.ca/app/scr/cc/CorporationsCanada/fdrlCrpSrch.html?locale=en_CA) does not have financial companies.

A list of financial companies is given [here](http://www.osfi-bsif.gc.ca/eng/wt-ow/Pages/wwr-er.aspx?sAll=1).

Answer (score 1):

You need to know in what province that business was incorlorated in. Then, you can look up in that province's registry of businesses. For example, in Quebec you would look at the Registre des entreprises.

[Here is National Bank of Canada's page as an example:](https://www.registreentreprises.gouv.qc.ca/RQAnonymeGR/GR/GR03/GR03A2_20A_PIU_RechEntMob_PC/index.html?T1.CodeService=GR03A20&Clng=F&WT.co_f=204.48.79.158-3699757216.30616604#fiche)